# Postgres/Python subfield sanity check

Tags: python, postgresql, dbeaver

I am struggling with a sanity check. I have a PostgreSQL database on dbeaver and a table named Album. I am trying to automate a sanity check. In the column ArtistId I have a small click-in window on the right, once I click on it I get a new window with ArtistId and Name. For every distinct ArtistId I wish to check whether the name is the corresponding ArtistId. So far I managed to get the table (Album) in a data-frame but I can not reach the sub-field. Thank you in advance for any help.

1. Problem 1: I need to access the sub-field (Database window picture).
2. Problem 2: I need to check for every row of the sub-field whether the artist name is 'Iron Maiden' or the corresponding artist name based on ArtistId that the user provided.

My code retrieves the entries in the database.

```
    def get_entries(artistID):
        artistID = int(input("Enter an artist_id from the available in postgresql :"))
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE ArtistId = %s",connection, params=(artistID,) )
        return df
```

For problem 1) I found the following code `SELECT x.* FROM Artist x WHERE x.ArtistId = 4` which can give me access to the sub-field.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV8dr.png) [Database window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OovHL.png) [Database er diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXmff.png)

Comment: Please give us a SPECIFIC problem. We can't do much with a description of what you want to do and pictures. We need to know exactly what's going wrong for you... can you include a code snippet showing the problem along with a specific question pertaining to the problem? Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Seth Do the new edits offer any additional explanation to what I am trying to pursue?

Comment: Better, but could you add a question?

Comment: In my example I want to check whether 90 is Iron Maiden for every occurrence of the particular ArtistId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the Problem 1 was a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Album a
CROSS JOIN Artist b
Where a.ArtistId  = b.ArtistId
AND a.ArtistId = 90
```

The solution to the Problem 2 was python line:

#This line returns the rows in my dataframe that are not same to the user_input

```
df.loc[df.ArtistId != artistID]
```